# Returning only updated fields from database

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I'm building stored procedure which will be used by my Web API application. Now, I have multiple databases and multiple stored procedures which returns me all data which is specified by API contract. What I want to do is to customize my SP's in the way that they are going to return me only updated rows. E.g. I have 10 columns in a table, and user changes 2 columns, stored procedure check which columns are affected and returns me only those and for all other columns it should return null. So far I was thinking to create new table which will store `ProductId` and `UpdatedFields` so when update SP is triggered, it will update Name and Category fields and store those column names in new table under `UpdatedFields` like comma separated strings (`Name`, `Category`...) and on retrieving member data SP will not return `Price` nor `Quantity` (those should be null) but just `Name` and `Category`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I did something very similar to this using a modified at (datetime) field in the orgininal table. That way i could bring back fields that had been updated in a specifit time frame without the need for additional tables. Dont know if that could work for you as well

Comment: Our motivation is different, but we log changes to certain tables with an idenifier, field changed, changed when, and old value.  You probably don't need the old value.  But you want mulitple records, not single records with lists.  That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: OK, I have two roles. One is owner and one is consumer of product. We also have `Products` table. Owner changes just `Name` of Product. When consumer calls GET `Product` SP returns that product but only changed field in this case `Name` for other ones it returns null.

@DevN00B Can u please explain that approach a little bit more?

Comment: it probably wouldn't work in this case as i have just read your question more carefully. Why would you want to return null values for other records? my mothod would only bring back rows that had been updated but you could use a combination of mine and @DanBracuk methods to work. Basically my way was simple...it just time stamped the ModifedAt field using GETDATE() whenever a record was updated

Comment: I want response to be smaller as it can be. It will be consisted from couple of objects and if I want to return all of them via API it will not fit for me. Any of null values would be suppressed by API. that's the idea

Answer (score 1):

You could use @DevN00B's suggestion to identify modified rows, then use a `CASE` for each column to either return the new value or `NULL`

The `UPDATE` performed by the owner would set the ModifyDate to `GETDATE()` for the existing record and insert the changed record with a `NULL` ModifyDate

The GET procedure would then look something like the following

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN New.Name = Old.Name THEN NULL ELSE New.Name END
CASE WHEN New.Category = Old.Category THEN NULL ELSE New.Category END
...
FROM Product Old
JOIN Product New
ON Old.ProductID = New.ProductID
AND Old.ModifyDate IS NOT NULL
AND New.ModifyDate IS NULL
```

Multiple `UPDATE`s will make things more complex, as you will have a row for each change, which in general won't have all the columns changed by all the seperate changes